# Public ArrayAdapter for ListView

Tags: android, listview

Referring to the below codes. I wanted to know why do I need to put in one object and not all the objects from the strings. This codes are from a Custom ListView Adapter.

[public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Working Fine

```
public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] first, String[] second, String[] third) {
            super(context, R.layout.listview_item, first);
            this.context = context;
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
            this.third = third;
        }
```

Error if I do this.

```
public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] first, String[] second, String[] third) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, first, second, third);
        this.context = context;
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }
```

Error : The constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, int, String[], String[], String[]) is undefined

Original Source

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] first;
    String[] second;
    String[] third;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] first, String[] second, String[] third) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, first);
        this.context = context;
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }
```

Comment: `super` calls the constructor of the class you are extending, and if you look at the link you have provided you will see it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about the principle of [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in Java. Your class is extending [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

If you take a look at it, you see that no constructors of type `ArrayAdapter(Context, int, String[], String[], String[])` are defined for this class.

That's why you can't do `super(context, R.layout.listview_item, first, second, third);`